# facebook app doesn't auth for my app

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook

I have a problem to connect facebook app with my app.
I don't know much about facebook sdk, so I simply copy & paste from the facebook sample app.
(i only need upload image with some text).
it works well unless facebook app is installed on the device, but if a device has facebook app, it seems like can't get the login information.
I think it is because of facebook app doesn't ask auth for my app unlike safari browser.
What do I have to do?

Comment: Which verison of the facebook app you are using?

Comment: I think I downloaded this https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/preview

Answer (score 0):

Please Download the latest version of Facebook app (4.1.1) from app store. The Single Sign On(SSO) only supports in the latest version of Facebook application.